# Windows desktop application read session data from browser

Tags: python, c#, node.js, angular, desktop-application

I'm writing a desktop and web app, Just need to know how can i authorize this desktop application with same open web app browser after installed?

Answer (score 0):

if you mean to authorize your desktop app via the login of user from any web browser, you can use TCP/UDP socket or also for example , call an api every 2 seconds to check is user is loged in or not. in web browser , if user had be loged in , you can set login state with its ip or other data in database to authorize the user from desktop app.

Comment: if desktop application call api how can server know him with out web browser data such as token or secret key
 i wont to share this key between web and desktop

Comment: the server connection authentication is different from the user authentication. you need to authenticate the server connection first from desktop to server with every way you want. then with that connection , you can check for example current IP that desktop has is logged in or not. ...

Comment: if logged in , add a unique token to user in database and ask user in web browser to accept the connection of desktop if is authorized. then you can tell desktop from server  that you are authorized with this token that is generated from server. now desktop can communicate with that token. of course this way may has bugs and needs a complete analyse for find best way.

Comment: may be current ip that desktop is used not good idea to use in authorized because this ip may be changed 
my problem in first time desktop lunch must call server with api and server know him without login data

Comment: i think it will not change in one internet connection with out any use of vpn or proxy. if it did he/she will login again. you could use ip and os details to find the user. for server authentication as i said , you need to authenticate application access in general before authentication of user to use public api. i means you need two level authentication. i dont think any data can help you like ip to find a user before login.(because of browser access) . otherwise user have to use a name or id or a data to send to server, now server can find the user and its connections.